# G*Power total sample size between-within ANOVA

Tags: statistics

When calculating the required sample size in G*Power for a repeated-measures, between-within interaction ANOVA, what does the 'total sample size' in the output refer to? The number of participants required per group or the combined total of all groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the total number for all groups.  There's an example in an early [paper/tutorial](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPowerShortTutorial.pdf) here on page 56.  It shows six groups and the need for N=90 (total sample size) with n=15 per group.

A more recent example, from the [G * Power 3.1 manual](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPowerManual.pdf), states the defining verbiage in example 1.2.3, "... a total sample size of  N = 176 (i.e., 88
observation units in each group)."